# How to append csv data as a ROW to another existing csv and move to 1st row. When i try to append all the data is at the bottom of the first column

Tags: python, csv, append, row

I have a csv with one row of data. It represents legacy headers that I am trying to append as 1 new row (or consider it as many columns) in a second csv. I need to compare the legacy header with the second csv's current headers, so after i append the data from the first csv i want to move it so that it's the first row too.

The issue right now is that when i append my data from the first csv it just all goes to the bottom of the first column.

See below for my code. How can i make it so that it takes the 1 row of data in my first csv and appends it to my second csv as ONE NEW ROW. After how would i move it so that it becomes the first row in my data (not as a header)

```
with open('filewith1row.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as reader:
    with open('mainfile.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8') as writer:
        for line in reader:
            writer.write(line)
```

Please help!! Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to import the `csv` files, combine the two, and then [overwrite](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) the original `mainfile.csv`.

I have created some dummy data to demonstrate. Here are the test files that I used:

##### mainfile.csv

```
Fruit,Animals,Numbers
Apple,Cat,5
Banana,Dog,8
Cherry,Goat,2
Durian,Horse,4
```

##### filewith1row.csv

```
Fruta,Animales,Números
```

---

This is the code that I used to combine the two CSVs.

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd

mainfile = pd.read_csv('mainfile.csv', header=None)
one_liner = pd.read_csv('filewith1row.csv', header=None)

mainfile.loc[0.5]=one_liner.loc[0]
mainfile = mainfile.sort_index()       
mainfile.to_csv('mainfile.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

### Output:

mainfile.csv

```
Fruit,Animals,Numbers
Fruta,Animales,Números
Apple,Cat,5
Banana,Dog,8
Cherry,Goat,2
Durian,Horse,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two files into a new one.

**UPDATED** to address comment from ScottC.

```
cat hdr.csv                                                                                                                                                                
first_col,second_col,third_col

cat data.csv                                                                                                                                                              
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9


with open('new_file.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    with open('data.csv') as data_file:
        new_file.write(data_file.readline())
        with open('hdr.csv') as hdr_file:
            new_file.write(hdr_file.readline())
        new_file.write(data_file.read())


cat new_file.csv                                                                                                                                                          
col1,col2,col3
first_col,second_col,third_col
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Comment: OP did not want the new line in the header row. Which is deceptive because they also asked for the new line to go into the 1st row.